# How to redirect ssh port to another port by username?

Tags: ssh, iptables, docker, ubuntu-20.04

I have `sshd: Listen 2222` on server, and what I want to do is:
`ssh -p 2222 userA@ip`, and server finds `userA`, then redirects this connect to `6122` port of this server, but I don't want to modify on my local machine, because there are hundreds of users, all these users have their own docker container, e.g., for user `userA`, I run `sshd` on its container, and expose `22` port to `6122` port of host. So I want to use `iptables` or other ways to forward `Host:2222` to `Container:6122`.

I have tried commands like below:

```
iptables -t nat -A userA_rules -p tcp --dport 2222 -j REDIRECT --to-port 6122
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner userA -j userA_rules
```

But it doesn't work. I'm new to `iptables`, so I'm not sure where wrong.
Also I have tried to modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to use `Match User userA` block, but I failed either. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I highly doubt that this is possible.

Comment: Why it's impossible? If I can't just use `iptables` or `sshd_config` to do that, is there another way to do it?

Comment: You can do this with neither iptables nor the sshd config.

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding what you mean, but I don't know how to configure it. Can you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: I fail to see, that when you expose port 6122, why you can't simply instruct the user to connect to that port directly? Why instruct them to connect to one non-standard port, port 2222 , when you actually want them to connect to another non-standard ssh port 6122?

Comment: Due to the security requirements of the server, I cannot open these ports through the firewall without authorization, so I can only solve it through this method.

Answer (score 0):

The iptables owner module only works on locally generated packets  on the machine where packets are generated not on a remote server.

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html

```
owner
   This  module  attempts to match various characteristics of the packet creator, for locally
   generated packets. This match  is  only  valid  in  the  OUTPUT  and  POSTROUTING  chains.
   Forwarded packets do not have any socket associated with them. Packets from kernel threads
   do have a socket, but usually no owner.
```

But that UID/GID is not available outside of the server.

Iptables works on TCP/IP network packets. Packets have a destination IP destination port, source IP and source port but no property that says: they were generated by user `freshzy` or UID #123 on the source machine. So therefore iptables on the remote server simply does not have the information to do what you want it it do ; create a rule for one user from a remote machine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So there is no way to realize my idea? Because I use docker to manage multiple users, and I want all SSH requests to be forwarded to the corresponding container through port 2222, I made the above attempt.

Comment: For a completely different approach, that may suit your needs see my comment and answer on this old Q&A here https://serverfault.com/q/952832/37681

Comment: I browsed your answer and it seems to be the only feasible way, but I feel very strange because it seems that my needs are very simple and can be achieved by simply modifying the configuration, but now I have to use a more troublesome method. I do not understand.

Comment: @freshzy That's *often* an indication that it's not a good idea for some reason.

Comment: Docker is not designed to “manage multiple users”. That said, you may like the [HAproxy approach](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/route-ssh-connections-with-haproxy)